# How to handle different line end such as lines end with CRLF (\r\n) and line end with LF (\n) or CR (\r) in AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I am new to AWK, and the requirement is to split one of the field and append it to end of record / row, for this I am using awk command which I shared below.
However when the file is having different end of line such as CR or CRLF it is behaving differently.

awk command :

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "~" }; {fullname=$1}; {split(fullname, a, " ")}; { if (fullname=="TT") newmodifiedline=$0; else newmodifiedline=$0"~"a[1]"~"a[2]; }; { print newmodifiedline }' example.txt > example_modified.txt
```

When the example.txt file has CRLF as the end of line as below
[image]

The result will be where the appended fields is moved to next line. Which is not expected.
[image]

However when using the file with end of line is LF, I do get desired result and the appended values are correctly appended at the end of record as below.
[image]

Is there a way I could handle it irrespective of end-of-line character or set the end-of-line char to LR and then run the awk command? Please help.

Comment: Remove CRs with `sed -i 's/\r//g' file`, then run your `awk`. Or use `dos2unix`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for quick response, let me try with this.

Comment: `sed 's/\r//g'` will remove all `\r`s, not just the ones you care about at the end of each line. You also don't need sed when you're using awk as `{gsub(/\r/,"")}` would do the same as that sed script (but I still wouldn't suggest doing it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
{ sub(/\r$/,"") }
...other stuff...
' file
```

is probably what you want, otherwise see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/1745001)